# Add dot after section number

Tags: sectioning, formatting

```
\begin{document}

\section{Reading Assignment}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

but I want:

[image]

How can I do this without doing the following:

```
\begin{document}

\section*{1. Reading Assignment}

\end{document}
```

It is tedious to keep track of the numbers and I just want a dot after the number.

I have tried searching for the answer but I couldn't find anything else, maybe because idk how to word the question I'm asking.

Comment: section headings are defined in the document class and for some reason you have deleted that information from all your examples, so without knowing how your headings are defined it is hard to tell you how to change it.

Comment: sorry i was trying to give a MVP, it is `\documentclass[11pt]{article}`

Comment: With`\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}.}` in preamble ?

Comment: @Zarko - Your idea may seem natural, but it causes massive headaches when one has to create cross-references to sectioning units.

Comment: @Mico, you may be right, however, just now I see the same proposition in one answer on duplicate question :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load `titlesec` and add to your preamble:

```
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\enspace}
```

Comment: ah this is perfect and ty for flagging this as a duplicate that answered my q perfectly as well.